# Stored procedures in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

How can I write stored procedure or function in HQL? Is it possible? I haven't found any information about it.

The problem is that my app works with several Databases(Oracle, MSSQL, PostgreSQL) and I need to count Levenshtein distance in my query. Can I do it without writing 3 native SQL functions and queries for each database?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-sp) will help.

Comment: In example we call MySql prcedure through hibernate, but will it work with other databases? I need to write pocedure that generic for all databases.

Comment: HQL does not support Stored Procedures. And how do you think this would help? Levenshtein is implemented differently in these three databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to encapsulate discrepancy between Levenshtein function names in different databases in hibernate dialect. Below I will provide an example for Oracle and PostgreSQL. (I did not work with MSSQL)

1. The extended Oracle dialect:

```java
public class MyOracleDialect extends Oracle12cDialect
{
   public MyOracleDialect()
   {
      super();
      registerFunction( "levenshtein", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE(?1,?2)" ) );
   }
}
```

2. The extended PostgreSQL dialect:

```java
public class MyPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect
{
   public MyPostgreSQLDialect()
   {
      super();
      registerFunction( "levenshtein", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "levenshtein(?1, ?2)"));
   }
}
```

3. And now you can use the `levenshtein` function in your HQL.

```java
List<Integer> result = session.createQuery(
   "select levenshtein(word1, word2) from TestEntity",
   Integer.class
).getResultList();
```

**P.S.** I have faced with the following problem for PostgreSQL:
If the extension `fuzzystrmatch` was installed for the particular schema `TEST_SCHEMA`:

```sql
SQL> create extension fuzzystrmatch;
```

then you should specify this schema in the connection url:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=TEST_SCHEMA</property>
```

otherwise you will get an exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function levenshtein(character varying, character varying) does not exist. No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```